# How do I get leiningen to let me name my project what I want?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to create a new project with leiningen but I keep getting the message:

"Project names containing uppercase letters are not recommended
and will be rejected by repositories like Clojars and Central.
If you're truly unable to use a lowercase name, please set the
LEIN_BREAK_CONVENTION environment variable and try again."

I'm runnning it in powershell so I tried setting that environment variable to "true" or 1 but no dice. I don't understand how I get leiningen to let me name my project what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the LEIN_BREAK_CONVENTION to any value, including false or nil.

Using the Command Prompt on Windows:

Run: `set LEIN_BREAK_CONVENTION=true`, and then create your project.

Using PowerShell:

Run: `$env:LEIN_BREAK_CONVENTION=true` and then create your project with any name you want.

Comment: That worked on the command line but not in powershell but that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a similar problem if your project name ends in `jure`, with Leiningen saying to use the LEIN_IRONIC_JURE environment variable.

There'll be no problem from Clojars, etc.

I didn't try the LEIN_IRONIC_JURE trick, so not sure if it works. Instead, after creating the project with a dud name, I went through the created directories and changed all references to the name I wanted.

Comment: The idea is to stop people from creating projects named Clojure, for example. This flag works just like LEIN_BREAK_CONVENTION, so my answer above works for LEIN_IRONIC_JURE as well.